# p:message not displaying the list of errors properly

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I am using primefaces p:message tab for displaying error messages in screen. But the error message backgroud is not expanding as per the list of message.

```
<table width="95%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="width:40%" id="leftTd">
                        <p:outputLabel value="User Profile"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <p:messages id="profileMsgs" showSummary="true" showDetail="true" for="userProfileForm:loginIdText"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr valign="top">
                    <td width="35%">
                        <table width="100%" border="0">
                            <tr valign="top">
                                   <td width="30%" align="right">
                                        <h:outputLabel id="loginIdLabel"  value="Login Id*:" for="loginIdText"> </h:outputLabel>
                                   </td>
                                   <td width="70%">
                                        <p:inputText id="loginIdText" value="ADMIN" 
                                        style="width:90%;"
                                        >
                                        </p:inputText>
                                   </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr valign="top">
                                   <td width="30%" align="right">
                                        <h:outputLabel id="personalIdLabel"  value="User/Personal Id*:" for="personalIdText"> </h:outputLabel>
                                   </td>
                                   <td width="70%">
                                        <p:inputText id="personalIdText" value="ADMIN PERSONAL"  style="width:90%;"
                                        >
                                        </p:inputText>
                                   </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>   
                </tr>   
</table>
```

I am getting below result:

[image: wrong messages]

Expected result should be like

[image: expected messages]

Comment: Hi, can you please create a [mcve]. I suspect some css is involved that is not visible in the code you posted

Comment: Can you share the CSS definition of these classes: `.ui-messages, .ui-widget, .ui-messages-error`